# Change Apache Server Internal IP Address

Tags: apache-2.4, ubuntu-14.04

I have an Ubuntu machine (14.04) running just 1 website under apache (2.4.7)

I need to change the internal IP address of the machine but whenever i do i can no longer access the website.

As soon as i change it back to its old internal IP the site is fine.

Ive got no IP restrictions in my hosts files or anything like that.

Is there some other file where i have to change a binding or something?

Thankyou

edit:

To clarify the public IP hasnt changed so its not DNS related. Public IP stays 1.1.1.1

When i change private IP of the Ubuntu machine from 2.2.2.2 to 3.3.3.3 the website is not served internally or externally from the LAN (Perimeter firewall also changed to point 80 to 3.3.3.3)

Flip Ubuntu and perimeter firewall rule back to 2.2.2.2 and the sites served.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify it but, if you are accessing it via `domain name`, you have to consider that `DNS propagation` can take even longer than 24 hours, so you won't be able to access your website untill then unless you connect directly to the `IP`.

Or, you can also do this trick:

`nslookup yoursite.com 1.2.3.4`

Where `1.2.3.4` is a `DNS` server you are sure (you can still try if not sure) it has never had the need to resolve your `domain name` so it will give you the new IP you set for your server.

Comment: Im changing the LAN ip address not the public IP.

Comment: So, you have public ip `1.1.1.1` and private ip `2.2.2.2`, you change private one and then access `1.1.1.1` from the outside?

Comment: public IP stays the same. Private IP is going from 2.2.2.2 to 3.3.3.3. Change port 80 to 3.3.3.3 on my perimeter firewall. Website does not respond on 3.3.3.3 inside or outside of LAN. Change back to 2.2.2.2 and its served again. (Test inside LAN by adding an entry into my Windows machine host file pointing website to 3.3.3.3)

Comment: Alright, that info should be added to the OP, I'll update my answer if I have any idea.

Answer (score 0):

Look into the file `/etc/apache2/sites-available/<virtualhostname>` and check the Line `<VirtualHost *:80>`. Maybe you see an IP-Adress instead of the asterisk ("*"). Just you new IP-Adress there and restart the Service (`apache2ctl restart').

Comment: Thankyou for your advice. i can confirm having checked all the virtualhost files and the 000-default.conf that all say <VirtualHost *:80>

Comment: Okay, then have a look into you ports.conf. If that doesn't help, grep for your IP-Adress through all files in /et/apache2.

Comment: There is nothing in any file within /etc/apache2 with any IP specified. :-/